# Execute code after each period of time, JAVA

Tags: java, timer, timertask

I need to execute code after 10 sec, but it need to repeat itself each 10 sec..

I trying doing this but as I saw it start after period of time and dosent stop

```
final int sec = 1000;
final Timer timer = new Timer();
TimerTask tt = new TimerTask() {

  @Override
  public void run() {
    c.AddLifeToScreen(1);
  }
};

timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(tt,sec*10 ,sec*10 );
```

Comment: Use a `ScheduledExecutorService`?

Comment: What's wrong with the code you posted? Also, remember that any code you run like this will run in a different thread, which means it might run at the same time as your other code.

Comment: it just repeat it self after 10 sec without stop..I need that it start after 10 sec, wait 10 sec, and start again..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use threading to implement such functionality. I have give code below.

```
public class ThreadDemo extends Thread{

    @Override
    public void run(){
        while(true){
            // Your code here
            System.out.println(new Date());
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {              
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String []args){
        ThreadDemo t = new ThreadDemo();
        t.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: you can increase the millisecond to 10000. :)

Comment: My mistake..its works, just put it in the worng place

Comment: Yes you can, however the question author specifically stated `I need to execute code after 10 sec, but it need to repeat itself each 10 sec`. Which your example code *does not do*.

Comment: I just provided hint to achieve that in different way :)